# Proper styling for long If statements

Tags: python

After checking pep I wasn't seeing anything related to commenting at the end of large if statements.  Other languages for example HTML conventionally do this with a comment that looks like

`<!-- END 'descriptive name of block' -->`

So I was wondering what the proper way to do this with Python would be, normally I add the following on a new line after the if statement

```
if some_condition:
    [...]
# ~ if some_condition
```

That way if I have a lot of nested if statements things don't get too confusing.  Is there another way that this should be done, or how is this done professionally?

Thanks

Comment: The indentation is supposed to be a good indicator, no?

Comment: I'd probably wrap the if part in a function and just call that.

Comment: @thefourtheye I would agree apart from when there are a lot of nested if statements or the if statement spans longer than a page's length.

Comment: @sunshinekitty Perhaps if your `if` statement is longer than a page, you should move all that code into functions

Comment: You have bigger problems (if not already, surely down the line) if you have dealing with monster if blocks (especially if you have multiple level of nested statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example HTML conventionally do this with a tag that looks like
>
> ```
> <!-- END 'descriptive name of block' -->
> ```

That is not a tag, that's just a generic comment. You can just as well type `# End of if statement` but this is silly (in every language I can think of, because comments should add value).

You might as well type:

```
result = 2 + 2 # Adding 2 + 2
```

In Python specifically, the level on indentation is there to define code blocks; there is no specific need to mark the end of loops and other control structures.

> That way if I have a lot of nested if statements things don't get too
>   confusing. Is there another way that this should be done, or how is
>   this done professionally?

Good programmers try to avoid deep nested loops as these are a great source of bugs (as testing all possible execution paths becomes problematic). You should as a general rule, keep your loops shallow.

However, it is good to document and since documentation should add value, you should define *at the start of the loop block* what the following code block should do; rather than delimit it with your own markers.

Keep in mind that most programming editors automatically detect code blocks and will "fold" nested blocks with a click, this further devalues your comment.

You can look at the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more guidelines.

I should point out that code style guides are just guides, they are not mandated or enforced. You can deviate from them if you like.

If you are creating your own code style, document it :) and then be consistent.

Comment: Updated my post to reflect "comment" over "tag" since that's what I meant.  Thanks for the input, I am working with a few nested if statements and wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything.